# Editing a tabular:

Tags: tables, mathtools

So I have been working on an article about integration and its techniques, and at the ending I decided to add a tabular contains the most frequently functions and its antiderivatives, but the problem is that it looks ugly (lol), so any suggests to make it look fancier?
Here's the ugly tablar:

```
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}_+^*$ & $x^n $ & $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}^*$ & $\frac{1}{x}$ & $\ln \vert x\vert +c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $e^{\lambda x}$ & $\frac{1}{\lambda}e^x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $a^{\lambda x} $ & $\frac{a^x}{\ln(a)}+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\cos (\omega x) $ & $\frac{1}{\omega}\sin(\omega x)+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\sin (\omega x) $ & $\frac{1}{\omega} \cos(\omega x)+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$]\frac{-\pi}{2} ,\frac{\pi}{2}[$ & $\tan x$ & $-\ln \vert \cos x\vert +c$ \\ 
\hline 
$]\frac{-\pi}{2} ,\frac{\pi}{2}[$ & $1+\tan ^2 x \ \text{ou} \ \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$ & $\tan x +c$ \\ 
\hline 
$]0,\pi[$ & $\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$ & $-\frac{1}{\tan x}+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\cosh (\omega x) $ & $\frac{1}{\omega} \sinh (\omega x)+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\sinh (\omega x)$ & $\frac{1}{\omega x} \cosh (\omega x)+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\tanh (\omega x)$ & $\ln\left(\cosh x\right)+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\frac{1}{\cosh^2 x} \ \text{ou}\ 1-\tanh^2 x$ & $\tanh x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}^*$ & $\frac{1}{\sinh^2 x}$ & $-\frac{1}{\tanh x}+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$  & $\arctan x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$]-1,1[$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ & $\arcsin x +c$ \\ 
\hline 
$]-1,1[$ & $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ & $\tanh^{-1} x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ & $\sinh ^{-1} x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$[1,+\infty [$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ & $\cosh^{-1} x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Any edits or suggests to update it? I'll be thankful!

Comment: No, please, can you give the green check mark to @Zarko. It is very nice.

Comment: @Sebastiano Okay as you want, by the way thanks for the answer!

Comment: Very good...and thank you very very much for my request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you not provide any information about your document and its page layout, so the following solution use `article˛document class and its default page layout
- For fractions I would use `\mfrac`, a medium size fractions defined int the package `nccmath`
- for more vertical space around cells content I would employ macro `\setcellgapes` defined in the `makecell` package
- Instead of `tabular` is better touse `array` environment inside math environment. By this all `$` around math terms should be removed.

**Edit**:

- In the first version the content of the first table cell was centered due use of macro `makegapedcells`.
- So far I didn't figured out why, however with use `\makecell[l]{...}` this misalignment can be corrected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, nccmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \[
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\makecell[l]{\mathbb{R}_+^*} % <---
                & x^n  & \mfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}^*    & \mfrac{1}{x} & \ln \vert x\vert +c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}      & e^{\lambda x} & \mfrac{1}{\lambda}e^x+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}      & a^{\lambda x}  & \mfrac{a^x}{\ln(a)}+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}      & \cos(\omega x)  & \mfrac{1}{\omega}\sin(\omega x)+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}      & \sin(\omega x)  & \mfrac{1}{\omega} \cos(\omega x)+c \\
\hline
]\mfrac{-\pi}{2} ,\mfrac{\pi}{2}[
                & \tan x & -\ln \vert \cos x\vert +c \\
\hline
]\mfrac{-\pi}{2} ,\mfrac{\pi}{2}[
                & 1+\tan ^2 x \ \text{ou} \ \mfrac{1}{\cos^2 x} & \tan x +c \\
\hline
]0,\pi[ & \mfrac{1}{\sin^2 x}
                & -\mfrac{1}{\tan x}+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}      & \cosh (\omega x)  & \mfrac{1}{\omega} \sinh (\omega x)+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}      & \sinh (\omega x) & \mfrac{1}{\omega x} \cosh (\omega x)+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}      & \tanh (\omega x) & \ln\left(\cosh x\right)+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}      & \mfrac{1}{\cosh^2 x} \ \text{ou}\ 1-\tanh^2 x & \tanh x+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}^*    & \mfrac{1}{\sinh^2 x} & -\mfrac{1}{\tanh x}+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}      & \mfrac{1}{1+x^2}  & \arctan x+c \\
\hline
]-1,1[          & \mfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} & \arcsin x +c \\
\hline
]-1,1[          & \mfrac{1}{1-x^2} & \tanh^{-1} x+c \\
\hline
\mathbb{R}      & \mfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} & \sinh ^{-1} x+c \\
\hline
[1,+\infty [    & \mfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} & \cosh^{-1} x+c \\
\hline
\end{array}
    \]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is there `\mathbb{R}_+^*` shifted to the right? :-(

Comment: @Sebastiano, hm, seems to be caused by `\makegapedcell`. I will try to investigated what is going on. Without it, positioning in the first cell is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , it was really helpful!!

Comment: Now it is perfect!!!

Answer (score 3):

I thought of expanding the space of the table cells and aligning the first column on the left so that the real fields are correctly columned.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
If $c\in \mathbb{R}$:
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}_+^*$ & $x^n $ & $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}^*$ & $\frac{1}{x}$ & $\ln \vert x\vert +c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $e^{\lambda x}$ & $\frac{1}{\lambda}e^x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $a^{\lambda x} $ & $\frac{a^x}{\ln(a)}+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\cos (\omega x) $ & $\frac{1}{\omega}\sin(\omega x)+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\sin (\omega x) $ & $\frac{1}{\omega} \cos(\omega x)+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$]-\frac{\pi}{2} ,\frac{\pi}{2}[$ & $\tan x$ & $-\ln \vert \cos x\vert +c$ \\ 
\hline 
$]-\frac{\pi}{2} ,\frac{\pi}{2}[$ & $1+\tan ^2 x \ \text{ou} \ \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$ & $\tan x +c$ \\ 
\hline 
$]0,\pi[$ & $\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$ & $-\frac{1}{\tan x}+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\cosh (\omega x) $ & $\frac{1}{\omega} \sinh (\omega x)+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\sinh (\omega x)$ & $\frac{1}{\omega x} \cosh (\omega x)+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\tanh (\omega x)$ & $\ln\left(\cosh x\right)+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\frac{1}{\cosh^2 x} \ \text{ou}\ 1-\tanh^2 x$ & $\tanh x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}^*$ & $\frac{1}{\sinh^2 x}$ & $-\frac{1}{\tanh x}+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$  & $\arctan x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$]-1,1[$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ & $\arcsin x +c$ \\ 
\hline 
$]-1,1[$ & $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ & $\tanh^{-1} x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$\mathbb{R}$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ & $\sinh ^{-1} x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
$[1,+\infty [$ & $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ & $\cosh^{-1} x+c$ \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more (mine) solution. Because it is based on the (very) old `mdwtab`, almost forgotten package `mdwtab` I decide to write new answer. It has a features which make it very handy (to my opinion) for such tables as is OP ones:

- Define columns type dedicated for math content  (`Ml`, `Mc` and `Mr`).
- Define horizontal lines `\hlx{...}, where in ˙...` are parameters (in MWE below are used `v` and `h`, for others see packet documentation} defining vertical space  above and below line so that vertical lines aren't interrupted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, nccmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{9pt}
\begin{tabular}{|Ml|Ml|Ml|}  % <---
    \hlx{hv}                 % <---
\mathbb{R}_+^* 
                & x^n  & \mfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}                % <---
\mathbb{R}^*    & \mfrac{1}{x} & \ln \vert x\vert +c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}      & e^{\lambda x} & \mfrac{1}{\lambda}e^x+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}      & a^{\lambda x}  & \mfrac{a^x}{\ln(a)}+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}      & \cos(\omega x)  & \mfrac{1}{\omega}\sin(\omega x)+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}      & \sin(\omega x)  & \mfrac{1}{\omega} \cos(\omega x)+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
]\mfrac{-\pi}{2} ,\mfrac{\pi}{2}[
                & \tan x & -\ln \vert \cos x\vert +c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
]\mfrac{-\pi}{2} ,\mfrac{\pi}{2}[
                & 1+\tan^2 x \ \text{ou}\ \mfrac{1}{\cos^2 x} & \tan x +c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
]0,\pi[ & \mfrac{1}{\sin^2 x}
                & -\mfrac{1}{\tan x}+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}      & \cosh (\omega x)  & \mfrac{1}{\omega} \sinh (\omega x)+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}      & \sinh (\omega x) & \mfrac{1}{\omega x} \cosh (\omega x)+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}      & \tanh (\omega x) & \ln\left(\cosh x\right)+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}      & \mfrac{1}{\cosh^2 x} \ \text{ou}\ 1-\tanh^2 x & \tanh x+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}^*    & \mfrac{1}{\sinh^2 x} & -\mfrac{1}{\tanh x}+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}      & \mfrac{1}{1+x^2}  & \arctan x+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
]-1,1[          & \mfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} & \arcsin x +c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
]-1,1[          & \mfrac{1}{1-x^2} & \tanh^{-1} x+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
\mathbb{R}      & \mfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} & \sinh ^{-1} x+c \\
    \hlx{vhv}
[1,+\infty [    & \mfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} & \cosh^{-1} x+c \\
    \hlx{vh}                 % <---
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask you please ? How I can fill a column with a specific color ?

Comment: @Electroelf, this is new question ;-). Unfortunately, `mdwtab` is not compatible with `colortbl` or `[table]{xcolor}` packages, i.e. table used `mdwtab` cannot be colored.